How to do group_by and then subtract group mean from each entry in the group in Polars
In pandas I can calculate the centered grouped columns as follows for a dataframe with columns ['a','b','c']:
df[['b','c']] = df[['b','c']].sub(df.groupby('a')['b','c'].transform(mean))

What is the equivalent code in Polars?
I tried implementing it with sub in polars but it expects expression and not dataframe. I need the original dataframe as output and not the grouped version.

pandas transform is an example in the user guide: https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/migration/pandas/#pandas-transform - For an exact answer, you'll have to provide a sample dataframe / runnable code.

TLDR. In polars, this is achieved with the window function pl.Expr.over. Concretely, your pandas code would look as follows.
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("b", "c") - pl.col("b", "c").mean().over("a")
)


Applied to some sample data, this could look as follows.
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    "b": [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    "c": range(6),
})

shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 2   ┆ 0   │
│ 0   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   │
│ 0   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 5   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘

df.with_columns(
    pl.col("b", "c") - pl.col("b", "c").mean().over("a")
)

shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c    │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 0   ┆ 0.0 ┆ -1.0 │
│ 0   ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0  │
│ 0   ┆ 0.0 ┆ 1.0  │
│ 1   ┆ 0.0 ┆ -1.0 │
│ 1   ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0  │
│ 1   ┆ 0.0 ┆ 1.0  │
└─────┴─────┴──────┘

